# How to create a diagonal line on bitmap image with C

Tags: c, bitmap

How do I create a diagonal line with C, I want to get four coordinates and create the most perfect diagonal line, but I want to draw it pixel by pixel. The problem is I don't know how to do this when the image is not "a square".

What I have till now:

```c
// try one
    for (int i = ystart, j = xstart; i < yend && j < xend; i++, j++)
    {
        printf("%d ", distance);
        image[i][j].rgbtRed = 255;
        image[i][j].rgbtGreen = 255;
        image[i][j].rgbtBlue = 255;
    }

// try two
    int distance = sqrt(pow(xend - xstart, 2) + pow(yend - ystart, 2));

    for (int w = 0, i = ystart, j = xstart; w < distance; w++)
    {
        image[i][j].rgbtRed = 255;
        image[i][j].rgbtGreen = 255;
        image[i][j].rgbtBlue = 255;

        i++;
        j++;

        if (i > yend - 1 || j > xend - 1)
        {
            break;
        }
    }


// I also have a two-dimensional (the image) array and width and height of the image, the image I'm using is 600x400, completely black and I want a diagonal line based on the parameters of the function
```

Comment: You could implement [Bresnham's line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm).

Comment: I will try it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the line formula from middle-school algebra class, "y = mx + b", and calculate the ideal y for each x.

To draw a line from (1, 7) to (6, 10) you might do this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void draw_pixel (int x, int y) {
  printf("draw pixel at (%d, %d)\n", x, y);
};

void main () {

  float m = (float) (10 - 7) / (6 - 1);

  float y = 7;
  for (int x = 1; x <= 6; x++) {
    draw_pixel(x, (int) round(y));
    y += m;
  };

};
```

Which does this:

```
draw pixel at (1, 7)
draw pixel at (2, 8)
draw pixel at (3, 8)
draw pixel at (4, 9)
draw pixel at (5, 9)
draw pixel at (6, 10)
```

You'll note that this doesn't work so well when `abs(x2 - x1) < abs(y2 - y1)` as it won't draw a continuous line.  To solve that, you have to use a different formula, `x = my + b`, which is accomplished in the same way but by swapping every x and y value, so that the `for()` loops over each y value and calculating the x, instead of looping over each x value and calculating the y.

Comment: I implemented this, using an if to handle `abs(x2 - x1) < abs(y2 - y1)`, which seems to work pretty well, but what is the difference between this approach and Bresenham? Is there a case where the current approach does not work?

Comment: @WemersonJesus It's probably the same algorithm.  The internet has a thing for pretending that basic math is something so advanced that someone deserves to have it named after them and then describing it in the most obscure terms possible in order to try to make it look advanced.  Even if it is different, any perfect line algorithm is going to have to choose the same pixels as this one, so I wouldn't bother deciphering that Wikipedia page.

Comment: hahaha, well I've heard that Bresenham doesn't use floating-point numbers or divisions, anyway, I don't know if it's my mistake, but I was testing a little bit more today and it doesn't seem to work so well when the idea is to draw from a point other than the top on the left side (a line from bottom-left to top-right for example)

I [posted it here](https://gist.github.com/wejesuss/ba4641fd2baae8fbe49b82387629b88e) if you're interested

Comment: I tested with Bresenham, no problems whatsoever, however, it's a bit different and a little more complex to understand, I will go with the first for now, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Drawing it using a naive line-drawing algorithm using the [cartesian formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation) for a line in plane won't look well:

```
dx = x2 − x1
dy = y2 − y1
for x from x1 to x2 do
    y = y1 + dy*(x − x1)/dx
    matrix[x, y] = BLACK
```

It works if you want to do the homework, but it does not work if you want to make a good software.  In the past, with the old diplays, this was a problem.  It was difficult to make a program to draw a line that was visible like a line.

There are many [algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_drawing_algorithm) to do it.